# multiple submit buttons from multiple custom controls messing up the postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I currently have a scenario where i am including two custom controls into a page, where each custom control has a submit button. The submit button works as long as only one control is added to the page, but once the second control is loaded both of the submit buttons stop working, the control never goes to the submit_click method in the custom control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be handling click events in your custom control class and not processing on submit.

Comment: Ummm... i think i wasn't clear on my post but click events for each of the buttons is handled in the custom control itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the 'UpdatePanel' in case you have multiple controls which send data to the web server.

You should put both of your user controls in two separate Update Panels and so both will work and will also not break the functionality of either of the controls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, please try and let me know.. if it works for you then please accept the answer so that anyone else who finds a similar problem can get a ready solutions..